# Implementing Async/Await in Node/Express app

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

I am running into a sync/async issue with my program and am having a hard time implementing async into my middleware. I have tried a few times and broken it a bunch, what would be a fairly simple way to implement async await?

Here is the route

`router.post("/testmedia", uploadFiles, testMedia);`

Here is the middleware

```
const uploadFiles = (req,res,next)=> {
    let b2fileIDs = [];
    let savedPhotoLinks = {};

    upload(req,res,function(err){
        req.files.forEach(function(image){
            var b2accountId;
            var b2authToken;
            var b2uploadURL;

            //console.log(image);
            b2.authorize()
                .then(function(auth){
                b2accountId = auth.accountId;
                b2authToken = auth.authorizationToken;
                                    }).then(function(ret){
                b2.getUploadUrl(process.env.B2BUCKET_ID)
                }).then(function(cb){
                                    b2uploadURL = cb.uploadUrl;
                b2authToken = cb.authorizationToken;
                }).then(function(cb){
                b2.uploadFile({
                    uploadUrl: b2uploadURL,
                    uploadAuthToken: b2authToken,
                    filename: 'test',
                    data: image.buffer
                }).then(function(cb){
                    var uploadLink = {link: cb.fileId};
                    b2fileIDs.push(uploadLink);
                }).then(function(){
                    successFn(response){
                    console.log(b2fileIDs);
                    //Save ID's to DB here

                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("This is an ERROR " + error );

                });
            })
                console.log("1");

            console.log('2');
        })
        console.log('3');
        console.log(b2fileIDs);
    })
    console.log('4');
    next();

};
```

The problem is that when I upload multiple files the async nature moves on without capturing the `b2fileIDs` line.

Comment: I don't see any `async` or `await` in your script? What have you tried? Remember that you can only `await` `Promises`

Comment: This is the script that works now, not the broken one. So I was looking for a good way to do this so I can wrap my head around ``async``. I'm going to have to do this a few more times I'm sure.

Comment: I am struggling where to call await, because with the ``.next()`` there is some semblance of order, where I can just use a callback function to make sure that I get all of my console.log's so I know what I'm receiving back. Now I have to put functions in variables, now will I know that I am receiving the informaiton back and how do I call that in async? This a complex route for me and I have tried many iterations and broken each one.